# Эффект фона

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать эффект, который подчеркнут на картинке красным? [image]

Comment: >подчёркнит на картинке красным?

это как понимать?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что изображение больше не доступно и суть вопроса становится неясной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это скорее всего нарисовано. Рисуем 2 картинки (градиент с прозрачным низом). Одна будут служить бордюрами по бокам, а другая - заливка между бордюрами.